# Error CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to cascade a dropdown menu to display the country code of the selected country from the dropdown menu, however, I got the following error message on the razor page:

Error CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DisplayCountryModel'
and this:

"CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type."

```
            <EditForm Model="@DisplayCountry">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary /> 

            <div class="col-12 row">
            <label class="col-12 font-weight-bold">Country Name:</label>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="DisplayCountry.CountryName" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            @foreach (var item in Countries)
            {
            <option value="@item.CountryCode"> @item.CountryName </option>
            }

            </InputSelect>
            &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => DisplayCountry[0].CountryName)" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 row">
            <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">Country Code:</label>
            <InputText id="CountryCode" @bind-Value="@DisplayCountry.CountryCode" placeholder="CountryCode" class="form-control" />
            &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => DisplayCountry[0].CountryCode)" />
            </div>

            <br />
            <div class="col-12 row">
            <span class="col-2"></span>
            <input type="submit" class="form-control col-1 btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
            </div>
            </EditForm>
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately You've posted 80 lines of unformatted code, without any indication of where the problem is. Please reduce this to a [mcve], and put some time into formatting your post as readably as possible.

Comment: I suspect the problem is `DisplayCountry[0]` though - what do you expect that to mean, given that `DisplayCountry` is a `DisplayCountryModel`? What would indexing it mean?

Comment: When i take [0] out, it works but does not display the code of the selected countryName, so i thought that might fix it.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you'd expect that to fix anything, but the structure of your page is also pretty unclear to me, partly because you haven't included any indentation. I suspect you basically need to do more research into "accessing the selected item in Blazor drop-downs"